# ImportError: No module named django_baker

Tags: python, django, python-import

I have installed django-baker from pip by `sudo pip install django-baker.` on macOS .The module can be found in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages,but I am not able to import this package.I have tried `sudo chmod -R go+rX /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`,but with no effect.Is there something wrong with path  or the installation?

Comment: Sanity check: how are you trying to use it?

Comment: Check that the directory where it installed is in your `sys.path`.

Comment: @user73657:How would I do it?

Comment: @user3615045 Run your python shell, then `import sys; print(sys.path)`